# ISPconfig 3 Per-user web directories on single domain

Tags: apache, configuration, dns, debian, virtual-machine

I have ISPconfig 3 (installed with [this instruction](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p5)) on virtual server so I would like to set up per-user web directories with single domain, so each client could have web site like `www.example.com/~username`

How can I set this up?

OS: Debian 7.6

Software version: ISPConfig 3.0.5.4p3

Answer (score 0):

Instead a directory why don't assign a subdomain to each client so you'll have `client1.example.com`, `client2.example.com` and so on. Easy with ISPConfig!